# Distance Between Parametric Curve and Plane as a Function of Time

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, 3d, parametric

Find the distance from the curve **r**(t) = cos t**i** + sin t**j** + t/(2pi)**k** to the plane -x-y+z=1 as a function of time.

I suspect that this problem, which presumably asks for the *shortest* distance between the curve and plane, involves projections of some form. However, it is the time aspect of the problem that is confusing me somewhat. How should I approach this?

Comment: I believe that the question is asking for the equation of the varying distance between the point and the plane. Given the equation $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$ of a plane and a point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ there is a formula for the distance from the point to the plane which can be derived in a straightforward manner from the vector projection of the point onto the plane. That is the formula  you need.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales So would I use the scalar component of the projection equation i.e. |a*b|/||b||?

Comment: The idea is to obtain the length of the difference between the position vector and its vector projection onto the plane, so you want the vector projection $\dfrac{a\cdot b}{|b|^2}b$.

Comment: I believe I may have misled you on my previous comment. If you project the position vector of the curve onto the normal vector of the plane, then the length of that vector is the distance of the point from the plane.

Comment: So that is the scalar projection onto the normal vector.

Comment: cos ti is nonsense as vectors are not in the domain of cos.  If you mean (cos t)i, then edit your question.

Comment: You have $\mathbf r$ as a function of time. Simply compute the distance of this point from the plane using any of the usual methods. You will end up with another function of time.